# Is there any way to get READ_PRECISE_PHONE_STATE permissions on android without manufacturer access?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-manifest, android-permissions

I am kinda new to android development.

For my internship I need to develop an app that can read phone signal strengths (RSSI and such).

Most of this data is easily retrieved through telephony manager, however, some data (crucial to my project) seems to be locked behind this PRECISE_PHONE_STATE permission which is a protected permission. from what I've seen, the only way to gain access to this permission is if device manufacturers give me this permission.

Is there a workaround? The company I am doing this internship for is too small to be noticed by these big manufacturers, so I fear the official way will not be possible.

Unfortunately, Rooting is not an option since our solution needs to be available for different devices regardless of manufacturer.

Comment: "Is there a workaround?" -- we do not know what *specifically* you are seeking a workaround for. All that we know is that it is "some data".

Comment: try telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS) ?